# Carrierwave remote url and choose file validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If a user chooses a file (photo) and as well as type in a URL for the `:remote_image_url` I wanted to know how best to validate this scenario or handle this experience?

I'm using fileupload js from http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html

Comment: What do you think should happen?

Comment: I was thinking a data-dismiss call if either file or remote file field  is clicked. At the moment I have the remote image taking precedence.

Comment: sure, I think you could handle in javascript to only enable one to be chosen. If you'll write some code, and then come back here with an update with specific questions on how to do a specific thing, we can help.